# How to Build custom Kernel module for aosp13 for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux-kernel, android-source, android-kernel

**Followed Steps**

Add module to the menuconfig:

```sh
cd kernel/arpi/drivers/invcase/
```

```kbuild
# Invcase Device configuration
menuconfig INVCASE
    tristate "Inverse Characters Case"
    default y
    help
      Say Y to include this module
      Say N will not build this module
      Say M to build this module but not include to kernel yet
```

Append invcase to list of menu (kernel/arpi/drivers/Kconfig):

```diff
+ source "drivers/invcase/Kconfig"
```

Add module to Makefile:

kernel/arpi/drivers/invcase/Makefile or kernel/arpi/drivers/invcase/Kbuild

```make
obj-$(CONFIG_INVCASE) += invcase.o
```

Append invcase to list of modules:

kernel/arpi/drivers/Kbuild or kernel/arpi/drivers/Makefile

```diff
+ obj-$(CONFIG_INVCASE)     += invcase/
```

**Build the kernel**

```sh
cd kernel/arpi
$ export PATH=$HOME/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin:$PATH
$ ARCH=arm64 scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh \
  arch/arm64/configs/bcm2711_defconfig \
  kernel/configs/android-base.config \
  kernel/configs/android-recommended.config \
  ../../device/arpi/rpi4/can/linux_mcp2515.config

$ ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- make Image.gz -j $(nproc)
```

**Change permission**

The module is initialized or loaded by root user. Change the permission if needed:

device/arpi/rpi4/init.rpi4.rc

```rc
+ on boot
+     chown system system /dev/invcase
+     chmod 0600 /dev/invcase
```

Rebuild system image to include new module:

Note to change the kernel images and modules which is used for making AOSP system image. Follow the guide "Include custom kernel" for more details.

**Build AOSP:**

```sh
m all -j$(nproc)
```

Problem is that the module I am building is being built successfully but When try to check the wether kernel intialized successfully or not with this command `ls -l /dev/invcase`, it shows that file not found.